# How to replace elements in list of lists in given range?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I've defined list of lists, e.g.:

```
a = [[1,2,1,1,1],[1,1,3,4,1],[2,1,2,5,1],[1,1,2,2,3],[1,1,1,1,1]]
```

What I want to do is to create a loop which will be iterating through every list in list `a` and replace elements in given range (increasing by 1 when moving to next list) with zeros, so the output will be:

```
a = [[1,2,1,1,1],[0,1,3,4,1],[0,0,2,5,1],[0,0,0,2,3],[0,0,0,0,1]]
```

I've tried different ideas, but finally none of them seem to be working and I feel like I'm misunderstanding something.

I've tried:

```
k = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i][:k] = 0
    k += 1
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Is it a requirement that the list has to be in-place modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the last element of the last sublist should be zero.

```py
a = [[1,2,1,1,1],[1,1,3,4,1],[2,1,2,5,1],[1,1,2,2,3],[1,1,1,1,1]]
for i, row in enumerate(a):
    row[:i+1] = [0] * (i+1)
```

The 3rd line uses the Python's slice subscription, which we use to assign an iterable (list of zeros in particular) to it.

Comment: your current code creates the needed zeros, but resets the remainder elements of each sublist. 
Also, it is not idiomatic Python - `for in range(len(...))` should be avoided in favor of `enumerate`, when indexes are needed.

Comment: @jsbueno The OP wanted to mutate the initial list, not create a new one as you provided in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the basic way to do it:

```
a = [[1,2,1,1,1],[1,1,3,4,1],[2,1,2,5,1],[1,1,2,2,3],[1,1,1,1,1]]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i):
      a[i][j]=0
print(a)
```

Assuming that the first element of the first list should not be a Zero because it is "(increasing by 1 when moving to next list)"

Comment: Looks good except the reasoning after the word *because*. The example output shows that this is the intention.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = []
for i, sublist in enumerate(a, 1):
   b.append([0] * i  + sublist[i:])
```